# How to make a Crystal report with data from classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I am new to this tool, so I do not know how I can get the data of a class and show in a report.

I don't have a database, my info is stored inside variables inside classes. Like this (Folder Objetos):
[image: The top class is NFe]

My program does: Read a XML, validate with XSD, serialize in this classes.
What I want: Take that information and show in a report.

**It is possible to put my data from variables in a Crystal report? Where I start?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well crystal report can take many things  as " DataSource"  ranging from object, datatable, dataset etc etc.   without looking at the code it is hard to figure out where you are having issue.

basic syntax for crystalreport load datasource is

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument reportDoc = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
        reportDoc.Load("your RPT file");

reportDoc.SetDataSource(object)
```

here  instead of object you can use dataset, datatable etc.\

Is this what you were looking for ?

Added

```
reportDoc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["YourTableName"])
```

Also one more thing to note is if you report requires lets say 20 fields they all must be preset in the datatable. or else it will not work.  if it has any extra fields in dataset it will just ignore those

Comment: Yes :D
I was trying to populate a dataset, setting as dataSource of my Crystalreport file and showing in a CrystalReportViewer. I'm gonna try this tomorrow, thanks in advance.

Comment: When I try to use my top level object, says: "The data source object is invalid."

Comment: normally, depending on how the report was designed it may require you to use Datatable , so if you have created  Dataset.  in your dataset  give the table name reference to the reportdoc and it sould work fine.   edited above answer please look and post any feedbacks